# FindLabel not Defined in ArcMap labeling with Python Parser?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, labeling, python-parser

I'm trying to make an advanced label expression using the python parser and I keep getting the following error:

```
The expression contains an error.  
Modify the expression and try again.

Error 0 on line 0.   
Error running expression: FindLabel()   
Traceback (most recent call last):    
 File "<expression>", line 1, in <module>   
NameError: name 'FindLabel' is not defined
```

[image]

```
def FindLabel ( [Direction] ):
  return  "{}° {}' {}\"".format( [Direction].split("-"))
```

Can anyone tell me why FindLabel is not defined?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think there is a bug in their parser as I am not getting identical behavior between a Python prompt and the label expression evaluator.

Try the following as a workaround:

```
def FindLabel ( [Direction] ):
    return "{}° {}' {}".format(*[Direction].split('-')) + chr(34)
```

There were two problems:

1. **Due to a bug with the ESRI parser** (this is legal in pure Python), you cannot escape a double-quote with a backslash if the string is surrounded by double-quotes. Similarly, you cannot escape a single-quote with a backslash if the string is surrounded by single-quotes, although this is also legal in pure Python. Triple-quoted strings also don't work the same as at a Python prompt.

   Examples that work in a Python prompt but not in a Python label expression:

   - `"I am 6'2\" tall."`
   - `"""I am 6'2" tall."""`
   - `'I am 6\'2" tall.'`
   - `'''I am 6'2" tall.'''`

   To work around this, you can instead concatenate it or format it into the string separately.
2. The [`str.format()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) function expects args or kwargs, not a sequence. You can use the `*` operator to [unpack a sequence into arguments](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists), which is what I did above, and it works.

---

Side note -- because this is a 1-liner you can uncheck the "Advanced" box and just use the expression itself instead of a complete function:

```
"{}° {}' {}".format(*[Direction].split('-')) + chr(34)
```

Comment: The only other mention I could find for this bug was in the comments of this ArcGIS Idea: [Advanced Label Expressions with ArcPy](http://ideas.arcgis.com/ideaView?id=08730000000bsHb)

Comment: Thanks blah238! I went with the non-advanced syntax and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score -1):

It should actually give you a syntax error telling you your code block is invalid, because that's what's going on here.

Should look like this:

```
def FindLabel (Direction):
  return u"{}° {}' {}\"".format(Direction.split("-"))
```

Comment: The brackets are necessary for the label expression to work. See: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s800000027000000